# How to get both the output and return code with subprocess?

Tags: python

I'm using the `subprocess` module to execute my C program, and at the end I want to get both the return code and the output returned from the program. I tried this:

```
result = subprocess.check_output(['src/main', '-n {0}'.format(n)], universal_newlines=True)
```

The above captures the output of the program, it will only raise an error if the return code is non-zero. The point is that I do not want to raise an error on non-zero error code, instead I want to use it in an `if` statement, and if the return code is non-zero I want to re-run the process.

Now, if I change it to `run`, and call as:

```
result = subprocess.run(['src/main', '-n {0}'.format(n)])
```

Then, I can do `result.returncode` to get the return code, but when I do `result.stdout`, it prints `None`. Is there a way to get both the return code and the actual output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to capture output with `subprocess.run()`, you need to pass `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`.  If you want to capture stderr as well, also pass `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` (or `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to cause stderr to be merged with stdout in the `result.stdout` attribute).  For example:

```
result = subprocess.run(['src/main', '-n {0}'.format(n)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Or, if you are using Python 3.7 or higher:

```
result = subprocess.run(['src/main', '-n {0}'.format(n)], capture_output=True)
```

You may also want to set `universal_newlines=True` to get stdout as a string instead of bytes.